# Transfer type double[] over network

Tags: java, networking, java-8, double

I want to transfer the type double[] over a network, and then somehow manage to transfer it back into a double[] in the receiving side. I am not entirely sure how to do this. I tried to convert the String received to a char[] and then parse all the chars to a double[]. However this did not work, the double had different data. I need to do this to make a network protocol for opencv, to transfer Mat's easily.

So this is how the data gets sent:

```
private void send_info(int row,int col, double[] data) {
        //Convert data to String, separated by : to indicate change
        //char[] sendit = data.toString().toCharArray();
        out.println("INF:ROW:"+row+":COL"+":"+col+":"+data);
}
```

And this is how it is received:

```
private void setInfo(String input) {
        input = input.trim();
        input=input.replace("INF:","");
        String inputs[] = input.split(":");
        System.out.println(inputs[1]);
        int row = Integer.parseInt(inputs[1]);
        int col = Integer.parseInt(inputs[3]);
        //double[] data = magic(inputs[4]);
        // What I need ^
        frame.put(row,col,data);
}
```

Comment: What's "different"? The format of a `double` is IEEE 754; you should be able to read or write it as an 8-byte chunk portably.

Comment: Note that besides the inefficiency of converting the data to text and back, your approach can’t work as with your code the sent string will look like, e.g. `INF:ROW:100:COL100:[D@17a34e61`…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't convert them at all. Waste of time and space. Just do it directly. To send `double[] doubles`:

```
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
dos.writeInt(doubles.length); // send the array length
for (d : doubles)
{
    dos.writeDouble(d);
}
dos.flush();
```

To read:

```
DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
double[] doubles = new double[dis.readInt()];
for (int i = i; i < doubles.length; i++)
{
    doubles[i] = dis.readDouble();
}
```

Or you can use `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject()` and `ObjectInputStream.readObject()` to write and read the entire array at once. Or you can use NIO and `DoubleBuffer`: left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 2):

As an addendum to [EJP’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39522598/2711488), here an NIO solution:

#### sending

```
try(SocketChannel ch=SocketChannel.open(
        new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 12345))) {
    ByteBuffer buf=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(doubles.length*Double.BYTES+Integer.BYTES);
    buf.putInt(doubles.length).asDoubleBuffer().put(doubles);
    buf.clear();
    while(buf.hasRemaining()) ch.write(buf);
}
```

#### receiving

```
final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

try(ServerSocketChannel ss=ServerSocketChannel.open()
        .bind(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 12345));
    SocketChannel ch=ss.accept()) {

    ByteBuffer bb=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
    bb.limit(Integer.BYTES);
    while(bb.hasRemaining()) if(ch.read(bb)<0) throw new EOFException();
    bb.flip();
    int size=bb.getInt(), byteSize=size*Double.BYTES;
    if(bb.capacity()<byteSize) bb=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(byteSize);
    else bb.clear().limit(byteSize);
    while(bb.hasRemaining()) if(ch.read(bb)<0) throw new EOFException();
    double[] doubles=new double[size];
    bb.flip();
    bb.asDoubleBuffer().get(doubles);
    return doubles;
}
```

It’s obvious that the buffer management gets more complicated on the receiving side due to the double array length which is not known beforehand.

If we want to reduce the number of transfers, i.e. avoid a distinct I/O operation just for the first four bytes, the method gets even more complicated:

```
final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

try(ServerSocketChannel ss=ServerSocketChannel.open()
        .bind(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 12345));
    SocketChannel ch=ss.accept()) {

    ByteBuffer bb=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
    while(bb.position()<4) if(ch.read(bb)<0) throw new EOFException();
    bb.flip();
    int size=bb.getInt(), byteSize=size*Double.BYTES;
    if(bb.remaining()<byteSize) {
        if(bb.capacity()<byteSize) bb=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(byteSize).put(bb);
        else bb.compact().limit(byteSize);
        while(bb.hasRemaining()) if(ch.read(bb)<0) throw new EOFException();
        bb.flip();
    }
    else bb.limit(bb.position()+byteSize);
    double[] doubles=new double[size];
    bb.asDoubleBuffer().get(doubles);
    return doubles;
}
```

But note that the format is identical to the one created with the `DataOutputStream` in [EJP’s solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39522598/2711488), so you could combine, e.g. the NIO sending code with the old I/O receiving code…